Using a MongoDB Atlas DB from a Next.js app
I am trying to connect a MongoDB Atlas database to a Next.js app that I just started to build on Heroku. For that I am partly following this tutorial and also looking at an old Next.js app of mine that was using MongoDB.
The code for my React component is here:
import connectDB from "../../configDB";

export default async function ShowShops() {
  console.log("BEFORE : calling connectDB !!!!")
  await connectDB()
  console.log("AFTER : calling connectDB !!!!")
  const conn = mongoose.connection;
  conn.once('open', () => {
    console.log("connection-opened ?????")
  });

  return (
    <div>
      Hello ShowShops !!
    </div>
  )
}

Below is the configDB.js file content:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const DATABASE_URL = "mongodb+srv://user:paswd@mycluster.gofme.mongodb.net/myapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=myapp-DBCluster";

if (!DATABASE_URL) {
  throw new Error("Please define the DATABASE_URL environment variable inside .env.local");
}

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function connectDB() {
  console.log("STARTED : function connectDB !!!!")
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    };
  
    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URL, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      console.log("REACHED : return mongoose !!!!")
      return mongoose;
    });
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  console.log("REACHED : return cached.conn !!!!")
  return cached.conn;
}

export default connectDB;

After running this command:
% git add . && git commit -m "update testapp" && git push heroku main

I get the URL for checking my app: https://myappurl.herokuapp.com/
Pointing the web browser (Firefox) to the given URL, in  the Web Developer Tools console, I can see this:
The resource at “https://myappurl.herokuapp.com/_next/static/media/a34f9d1faa5f3315-s.p.woff2” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly. myappurl.herokuapp.com

​which I did not expect, but I do see in the logs on the server side the lines below:
remote:        BEFORE : calling connectDB !!!!
remote:        STARTED : function connectDB !!!!
remote:           Generating static pages (1/5) 
remote:           Generating static pages (2/5) 
remote:           Generating static pages (3/5) 
remote:        REACHED : return mongoose !!!!
remote:        REACHED : return cached.conn !!!!
remote:        AFTER : calling connectDB !!!!

One can see that:
console.log("connection-opened ?????")

is never reached.
Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or not doing that I should do, for this last line (connection-opened) to not be reached?
package.json file content:
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^8.7.3",
    "next": "15.0.1",
    "react": "19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-69d4b800-20241021"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


you'll find those console.logs in the heroku logs (server-side!), not in the browser.

@simon.ro. Right. Indeed I had missed this detail. Consequently what I observe is now different and I modified my post accordingly. Please take a look.

You are not defining the callback for the 'open' event until the connection has long been open.  I wouldn't expect the open event to fire multiple times.

@Joe. Do you mean that the lines await connectDB() and conn.once('open', () => {...}) are too far apart in my component code? If not I do not see what you mean in your comment.

The await connectDB() call executes the included function, which calls mongoose.connect and awaits it, then after that has returned, mongoose.connection.onnce('open', ... is called, establishing the callback, but the 'open' event has long fired by that point.
